# Can XPath concatenate two nodeset values? (for use in XForms)

Tags: xml, xpath, concatenation, xforms

I am wanting to concatenate two nodeset values using XPath in XForms.

I know that XPath has a concat(string, string) function, but how would I go about concatenating two nodeset values?

*BEGIN EDIT:* 
*I tried concat function.. I tried this.. and variations of  it to make it work, but it doesn't*

```
<xf:value ref="concat(instance('param_choices')/choice/root, .)"/>
```

*END EDIT*

Below is a simplified code example of what I am trying to achieve.

XForms model:

```
<xf:instance id="param_choices" xmlns="">
    <choices>
        <root label="Param Choices">/param</root>
        <choice label="Name">/@AAA</choice>
        <choice label="Value">/@BBB</choice>
    </choices>
</xf:instance>
```

XForms ui code that I currently have:

```
<xf:select ref="instance('criteria_data')/criteria/criterion" appearance="full">
    <xf:label>Param choices:</xf:label>    
    <br/>
    <xf:itemset nodeset="instance('param_choices')/choice">
        <xf:label ref="@label"></xf:label>
        <xf:value ref="."></xf:value>
    </xf:itemset>
</xf:select>
```

(if user selects "Name" checkbox..) the XML output is:

```
<criterion>/@BBB</criterion>
```

**However! I want to combine the root nodeset value with the current choice nodeset value.**

Essentially:

```
<xf:value ref="concat(instance('param_choices')/choice/root, .)"/>
```

or

```
<xf:value ref="(instance('definition_choices')/choice/root) + ."/>
```

to achieve the following XML output:

```
<criterion>/param/@BBB</criterion>
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? (I am fairly new to XPath and XForms)

p.s. what I am asking makes sense to me when I typed it out, but if you have trouble figuring out what I'm asking, just let me know..

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The evaluation of an XPath expression can not modify the structure/contents of an XML document -- it only selects (a set of) existing nodes**.

In order to produce a node that doesn't exist in the XML document, one must use other means in conjunction with XPath (such as XSLT).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I guess my solution will be to hard code the root with each choice... so then choice looks like <choice>/param/@BBB<choice>.. There were reasons I wanted to avoid this, but I might be able to sacrifice those reasons.

Comment: This answer is wrong, XForms makes it absolutely possible (indeed it is XForms' raison d'être).

Comment: Phil-Booth: This answer is correct. It states a well-known fact about XPath, not anything about XForms.

Comment: Dimitre, it may indeed be a well-known fact about XPath, but as an answer to this question about XForms, your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the `ref` attribute instead of the `value` attribute on your [`value` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#ui-selection-commonelems-value). The `ref` attribute is for binding elements to a single node, whereas the `value` attribute is for using the value from a resolved XPath expression.

There is also a small mistake in your XPath expression itself, so if you change your `value` element to this:

```
<xf:value value="concat(instance('param_choices')/root, .)" />
```

...you should find that it works correctly.

Comment: Anonymous downvote, nice. Here is the part of the XForms spec that supports my answer (see the bit about @value):

http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#ui-selection-commonelems-value

Comment: While I was very excited to see this solution, it did not work for me. With this solution: When I loaded the form, the checkboxes were preselected (which I do not want to occur), and when I submitted the data, no xml was produced at all.. :(

Comment: @iHeartGreek: Which XForms processor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic XPath expression construction is not yet supported in XForms. There is no such function as eval() for Javascript.

As a very limited workaround you could use an expression such as

`/*[name() = substring-after(instance('param_choices')/root,'/')]/@*[name() = substring-after(.,'/@')]`

Comment: Alain, why can't he just use `xf:value/@value` ?

Comment: xf:value/@value would give the string '/param/@BBB', not the corresponding node value!

Comment: Yes, exactly. Perhaps we are reading different questions? From the question that I'm reading, it says `"to achieve the following XML output: <criterion>/param/@BBB</criterion>"`. What does your question say?